# lambda each row in a column from dataframe that is not 'nan'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the below code how can I iterate the lambda for rows that are not "nan", "null" or in other words blank?

The output still appends ".pdf" to even the blank rows.

```
    model1      model2    model3     
 0  File1.pdf   File3.pdf File2.pdf
 1  File2.pdf   nan.pdf   File2.pdf
 2  File3.pdf   nan.pdf   File2.pdf
```

```
model_types = []
for col in df.columns:
    model_types.append(col)
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: f"{x}.pdf" if x != 'nan' else x)  # this part
```

Comment: Can you show some expected results? I'm not sure what you are going for here.

Comment: I'd like for the `nan.pdf` to not have the `.pdf` appeneded. like to iterate the lambda for the not null rows.

Comment: What is the type of you 'nan' values? If they are strings then this should work, but if they are numpy nans or None values then you need to account for that.

Comment: They are blank rows, nothing in them

Comment: Please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict('list')` (**before** running your loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have real NaNs you should be able to add '.pdf' directly **in a vectorized manner** and this shouldn't impact the NaNs.

```
model_types = []
for col in df.columns:
    model_types.append(col)
    df[col] += '.pdf'
```

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
model_types = list(df)
df = df.stack().add('.pdf').unstack()
# or
df = df.apply(lambda s: s+'.pdf')
```

Output:

```
      model1     model2     model3
0  File1.pdf  File3.pdf  File2.pdf
1  File2.pdf        NaN  File2.pdf
2  File3.pdf        NaN  File2.pdf
```

Comment: Be aware that the @mozway solutions work ONLY with "str", it won't work if you have "0" or any integers/floats in cells :)

Comment: @Drakax yes, good remark (I assumed this is not the case due to the provided example)

Answer (score 0):

First convert your nans to `None`.

```
df1 = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
for col in df1:
    df1[col].apply(lambda x: f"{x}.pdf" if x else None)
```

Comment: This also removes the `.pdf` from the non NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

For people who want a more "universal" solution which let you deal with:

- 0 and **integers**
- **floats** numbers
- pd.NA = **< NA >**
- np.nan = **NaN**

Creating DF:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[0,"File2",1.23], 'Col2':["File1",pd.NA,"File3"], 'Col3':["File1","File2",np.nan]})
df
```

| index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | File1 | File1 |
| 1 | File2 | <NA> | File2 |
| 2 | 1.23 | File3 | NaN |

```
df1 = df.applymap(lambda x: x+'.pdf' if type(x) == str else x, na_action='ignore')
df1
```

| index | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | File1.pdf | File1.pdf |
| 1 | File2.pdf | <NA> | File2.pdf |
| 2 | 1.23 | File3.pdf | NaN |